# How to retrieve models from .json file in ember.js

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js

Following is my folder structure

```
Sample/
  css/
  js/
    libs/
    data/
        employees.json
    app.js
  index.html
```

app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource("employees");
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: "localapps/EmberProjects/Sample/js/data",
  url: "employees.json"
});

App.Employee = DS.Model.extend({
  name : DS.attr("string")
});

App.EmployeesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find("employee");
  }
});
```

employees.json

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
        "name": "Title 1"
    },
    {
        "name": "Title 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when i try to fetch data from the .json file, ember.js automatically replaces the .json in the url with " ".

Original fetch call:

```
http://localhost/localapps/EmberProjects/Sample/js/data/employees.json
```

But ember trying to fetch data from

```
http://localhost/localapps/EmberProjects/Sample/js/data/employees
```

So no data is recieved from the adapter.

Comment: Is the Employees file expected to change? Why not load it using the fixtures adapter for now? Are running your application as a `file://` request in the browser or do you have a server?

Comment: I am running my app from apache server. No the employees files is not going to change. I tried with Fixture adapter and it is working. In angular js, backbone js and other similar frameworks i will fetch json data from my local .json file file to test before connecting to production server. I am trying to do the same in ember.js also

Comment: Could you rename `employees.json` to `employees`?

Comment: If i remove the .json extension from the employees, it is working. But is there is any solution available without replacing the .json extension

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@claptimes solution would probably work, but it copies the original implementation which I think is a bad practice since you'll have to manually keep it up to date to the latest version of ember data:)

Also I noticed you're setting the `url` property which has been deprecated for a while (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/eeb6162f65513caa19ce18887c3f4d1c2014d80c/TRANSITION.md#host-and-namespace-configuration).

Here is a solution that calls `_super` and doesn't override the complete method:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function() {
    return this._super(...arguments) + '.json';
  }
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the pathForType method return?

Comment: Good catch, was thinking in coffeescript still I guess ;)

Comment: Strange - this works for me that it loads the .json file but ember for some reason can not load it properly as a model. If I change it to the fixtureadapter the same json works. Anyone any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Could be anything: are you sure the correct JSON is received by Ember? Any console errors? Please start a new question with a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. It builds urls that look like this: things.json/1

Answer (score 1):

To add the `.json` ending to your requests, you could override the [`buildURL`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.4/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L395) call in the `RESTAdapter`. This should work:

```
DS.RESTAdapter = DS.Adapter.reopen({
  buildURL: function(type, id) {
    var url = [],
        host = get(this, 'host'),
        prefix = this.urlPrefix();

    if (type) { url.push(this.pathForType(type)); }
    if (id) { url.push(id); }

    if (prefix) { url.unshift(prefix); }

    url = url.join('/');
    if (!host && url) { url = '/' + url; }

    url += ".json";

    return url;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but all answers provided here didn’t work. I think that depends on the further development of Ember.js.

Actually I figured it out how to receive the data with the RESTAdapter. You have to add `?jsonp=?` to the path to your JSON file.

Your adapter should look like this:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: "localapps/EmberProjects/Sample/js/data/employees.json?jsonp=?",
});
```