# Loading .JSON file with Ember Data

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data

I want to load data from file komentari.json that is found within my folder and it changes when i insert something new, it is not always with just one comment in it. When I try to start my application it shows nothing.Here is my code.

app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();
App.Router.map(function() {
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
return this.get('store').find('comment');
}
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
namespace: "http://localhost/proba/",
url: "komentari.json"
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
comment: DS.attr('string')

});
```

index page

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
<ul>
{{#each item in model}}
  <li>{{item.name}}</li>
 <li>{{item.comment}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

komentari.json

```
{"comments":[{"name":"Name1",
             "comment":"Comment1"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined any mapping.
Try to apply what it's written here
[How to retrieve models from .json file in ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883902/how-to-retrieve-models-from-json-file-in-ember-js)